# How can I get the index of a widget in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can a little bit confuse on how should I implement the delete function.

[image]

By tapping the bottom button will add a Custom Card widget to the widget list that shows up on the top

This is the function for that

```
onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _variationCards.add(VariationCard(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      variation: Variation.empty,
                      index: _variationCards.length,
                      onRemoveCard: (index) {
                        setState(() {
                          _variationCards.removeAt(index);
                        });
                      },
                    ));
                  });
                },
```

The problems of the current setup are

1. Lets say I delete the second Card, now that the third Card became the second Card, but the index I passed to the third Card widget is still 2 when it is actually 1 now.
2. I need the index in the Card widget because I need to have additional widget for the first card, but now If I delete the first card, the second card index value will not be updated.

I think I am heading to the wrong path to implement this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: it can handle by statemanagement, do want me to do that using `riverpod`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use "**removeWhere**" method. Something like:

```
onTap: () {
              
                _variationCards.add(VariationCard(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  variation: Variation.empty,
                  index: _variationCards.length,
                  onRemoveCard: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      _variationCards.removeWhere((card) => card.SomeId == _someId);
                    });
                  },
                ));
              
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

The leading information should rather be a list of your defined class / model instead of widgets. You want widgets to update (rebuild) according to the underlying information / state in your app. Currently your *widgets* are created and added to your list on gestures (like `onTap`) and won't update themselves - that's why the indices are "wrong" in your case.

I would suggest a combination of a class / model representing a card while making use of the `ListView.builder` variant:

Class representing your card:

```dart
/// Currently only holds the Variation enum value, add whatever
/// defines your cards later on
class VariationModel {
  Variation variation;

  VariationModel(this.variation)
}
```

Your widget which displays the cards in a list:

```dart
/// Need to be filled with instances of this class, maybe passed
/// down directly to this widget or grabbed from something like
/// GetIt or Provider etc.
List<VariationModel> _variations;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  ListView.builder(
    /// +1 to include the button to add a new card at the end
    itemCount: _variations.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => index < _variations.length ?
      VariationCard(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        variation: _variations[index].variation,
        index: index,
        onRemoveCard: () {
          setState(() {
            _variations.removeAt(index);
          });
        },
      /// Add your widget (card) here which is used to add a new
      /// new card (in this case a new VariationModel instance)
      ) : Card(
            ...
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _variations.add(VariationModel(Variation.empty));
              });
            },
          ),
  ),
}
```

Since this approach is using the `ListView.builder` widget which builds the children (your card widgets) dynamically and the index is properly being updated since the widgets are going to rebuild now, it should work as you intend to.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little app using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) with your requirements (I think so at least), it maybe be of help to you:

[image]

The code is [here](https://github.com/warcayac/using_cards_list_with_GetX).